# How can var know of an undefined type?

Tags: c#, syntax

How can the implicit type variable `var` know a type that is not defined in the scope (using `using`)?

Example:

This is ok

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod        
    {
        var list = AStaticClass.GetList();
    }
}
```

But this is not ok

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod        
    {
        List<string> list = AStaticClass.GetList();
    }
}
```

In the last code snippet I have to add `using System.Collections.Generic;` for it to work.

How does this work?

Comment: What is "not ok" ? What do you *exactly* mean ?

Comment: Doesn't compile, the compiler will say unknown type `List<string>` (or something like that).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How does this work?

When the compiler does the type inference it replaces `var` with `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>` and your code becomes:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod        
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.List<string> list = AStaticClass.GetList();
    }
}
```

But since the compiler spits IL, the following C# program (without any `using` statements):

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var result = GetList();
    }

    static System.Collections.Generic.List<string> GetList()
    {
        return new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
    }
}
```

and the `Main` method looks like this:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string> Program::GetList()
    L_0005: pop 
    L_0006: ret 
}
```

As you can see the compiler inferred the type from the right hand-side of the assignment operator and replaced `var` with the fully qualified type name.

Answer (score 3):

Compiler actually knows the type. Even though you didn't shorten it with using compiler can still replace '`var`' with full type definition with namespaces `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`... the same way you could define your variable with that line without 'using' directive.